# Remove all characters in multiple filenames, that follow a specific character, in Mac OS

Tags: macos, bash, filenames, terminal.app, batch-rename

Trying to find a script, or app, that batch removes filename clutter following proper formatting.

For example this **Exercise [2009] previous version.png** into this **Exercise [2009].png**

I need the final character in all files to be "]" or the year/date, while preserving the filename extension.

I've tried a few scripts such as:

`rename ’s/_[^_]*//‘ *.png`

or

`for file in *.png; do mv "$file" "$(echo "$file" | sed ’s/\.[^.]*$//‘)”; done`

which either don't work, or simply remove the file extension after the last "."

I'm basically not sure if I'm changing the right characters in the script, or if these are even the best ones to use.

Answer (score 0):

Like this, using [Perl's `rename`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-about-rename-different-versions-and-usage-what-is-the-recommended-way-to/730895#730895):

```
$ rename 's/(.*\]).*/$1.png/' *.png
```

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand "remove -n" or how it relates to "dry-run". Also I need this to work on multiple files at the same time.

Comment: Check edited post

Comment: Thanks, but I'm getting this error: -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: You should have a copy/paste error

Comment: Can you copy the command you run + error on https://hastebin.com/ please ?

Comment: https://hastebin.com/share/adosuqipir.vbnet

Comment: Try to type `sh` or `zsh` then repaste the command. Seems strange. Don't the default shell is `zsh` on Macos??? You tagued 'bash'

Comment: My Terminal had a message suggesting I update to zsh, so I did. Retried your command but all it does is give me "quote>" on a new terminal line. No change in the filenames.. I found a different solution via ChatGPT btw, which is this - which is keying off the year 1984: `find . -name '*1984*' -type f -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "$(echo $1 | sed -E "s/1984(.*)(\.[^\.]+)$/1984\2/")"' _ {} \;`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution I've found elsewhere that works on any specified character or characters. It finds the last occurrance of the characters you specify in 3 parts of the command, removes it plus everything else up to the file extension, then readds the specified characters.

`find . -name '*1984*' -type f -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "$(echo $1 | sed -E "s/1984(.*)(\.[^\.]+)$/1984\2/")"' _ {} \;`

This particular example keys off the year "1984", so that "Exercise 1984 previous version.png" becomes "Exercise 1984.png".

Special characters such as "]" require a "" before it in each of the 3 parts

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).